# How to only count documents in mongo with populate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a little application with mongodb and for now i need to query a few counts with document population, but i cant understand how - should i use aggregate option or its possible somehow without aggreagation?

I did tried to put query in populate section, but that works only on population query, so i did get document1 with required field null

I want to query all document1, where document1.document2.document3.value === 123.

```
document1 {
  address: document2 {
     pobox: document3 {
        value: 123,
}}}
```

How its possible? Thanks!

Comment: Not completely clearly. Probably don't need populate. Are you saying you want to count the amount of subdocuments that match the query above?

Comment: I need something like join in sql. Main task is to get count of document1, where document1.document2.document3.key = value. I tried to achieve this with populate, but numbers were wrong. Only solution i found is rearrange required things over few array iterations, but im sure there must be a way to get this with single query, instead of js array walking

Comment: Are these separate documents in different collections, or nested documents in a single collection?

Comment: @Joe separated, inserted as 'refs' into document1. But they're should be count as subrefs to document1, as one document2 or document3 could be inserted in another document1 entity too.